# Regarding find.replace using interop.word in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have this code that superscript every number in between two x'es

```
doc.Find.Replacement.Font.Superscript = 1;
doc.Find.Text = "x([0-9]{1,5})x";
doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";
doc.Find.MatchWildcards = true;

doc.Find.Execute(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I would like to have a similar function that superscript all characters between two x'es and thought that maybe this would do the trick:

```
doc.Find.Replacement.Font.Superscript = 1;
doc.Find.Text = "x([a-z]{1,5})x";   <-------- characters instead of numbers
doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";
doc.Find.MatchWildcards = true;

...
```

But it doesn't work. Also i'm not sure what the following line does.

```
doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
doc.Find.Text = "x([a-wy-z]{1,5})x";   <-------- characters instead of numbers
```

Because you want the "x" to "end" the matching, so it can't be part of the matching :-)

```
doc.Find.Replacement.Text = @"\1";
```

Means that it has to replace the text between the `(...)` with the text between the `(...)` (so only the `x-es` are removed). Clearly the formatting is done on the replaced text. `\1` means the text that matched the first `(...)`. If you had multiple `(...)(...)` then they would be numbered `\1`, `\2`, ...